# Superponer una capa por encima de otra

Tags: css

necesito darle solución a este problema. He probado con algunos z-index pero no logro el resultado. El problema es que tengo una primera sección que debe estar por encima (parcialmente) de la que viene a continuación. A la segunda sección le puse un z-index negativo y visualmente; según el diseño, he logrado lo que se quiere, pero no puedo acceder al contenido de dicha sección, pues queda debajo de toda la capa anterior. Como dije ya, he probado con z-index pero no lo puedo solucionar.

Pueden verlo aquí http://banderastudio.com/#front-views. Los elementos de la sección "Views" tienen enlaces, pero son imposibles de alcanzar, y no funciona ponerles z-index positivo.

Gracias de antemano por cualquier ayuda.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

por lo que vi en el enlace todavia no lo has podido resolver.
El problema es que cuando uno utiliza la **propiedad z-index, los elementos deben estar posicionados**.

He modificado el código de tu web por consola y funciono, lo que hice fue lo siguiente:

```css
.inner-main{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Espero te sirva , saludos.

Comment: Ufff... Gracias por la ayuda, ya lo había resuelto, solo me falta actualizar para que funcione perfectamente. Un saludo...